# Bessel functions: proof that $J_0(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{i z \cos(\theta)}d \theta$.

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, special-functions

I encountered the above when dealing with the Bessel functions of the first kind, $J_n(z)$, specifically $n=0$.  Using the differential-equation definition of the Bessel function, I obtained the above question's equivalence to
$$I(z)=\int_0^\pi e^{i z \cos(\theta)}( \cos(\theta)+iz\sin^2(\theta))d \theta =0.$$

How is this proved?

Comment: What definition are you using for the Bessel function? The series definition?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I'm happy for a prospective answer/comment to use any widely-used definition. To obtain $I(z)$ I used the differential equation definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the series definition is best. The series definition of the Bessel function is

$$J_{\nu}(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\Gamma(n+\nu+1)\,n!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+\nu}.$$

We will expand $e^{iz\cos(\theta)}$ as a power series as follows:

$$e^{iz\cos(\theta)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(iz\cos(\theta))^n.$$

So integrating term by term (which we can do since our series converges absolutely and uniformly everywhere) we have

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}e^{iz\cos(\theta)}d\theta = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(iz\cos(\theta))^nd\theta = \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}i^nz^n\int_0^{\pi}\cos^n(\theta)d\theta.$$

Now we should make use of the identity (which you can prove by induction)

$$\int_0^{\pi}\cos^n(\theta)d\theta = \begin{cases}0 & n \text{ odd}\\\frac{(2n)!\pi}{2^{2n}(n!)^2} & n \text{ even}\end{cases}. $$

Then we have

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}e^{iz\cos(\theta)}d\theta = \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)!}i^{2n}z^{2n}\frac{(2n)!\pi}{2^{2n}(n!)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n!)^2}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2n}. $$

This is exactly what we wanted to show (noting that $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$).

Comment: Thank you. I know little about Bessel functions and this helped greatly!